# JavaFX: Canvas resizing not working properly

Tags: javafx, canvas

I have a JavaFX application where there is a canvas with purple background and 2 diagonal lines. I bound the canvas dimensions with its respective pane container. Each time when this canvas is redimensioned, I redraw it.

Follow the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public class TestPaintColor0 extends Application {

    private void printChange(ReadOnlyProperty<Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue, Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.printf("[%s] %10s.%-10s: %4.0f -> %4.0f. Canvas: %4.0f x %4.0f.\n",
                LocalTime.now(), observable.getBean().getClass().getSimpleName(), observable.getName(), oldValue, newValue,
                canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    private void repaint(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue, Canvas canvas) {
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // Should clear canvas.
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        // Paint background
        gc.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        // draw diagonals
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.moveTo(0, 0);
        gc.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.moveTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
        gc.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0);
        gc.stroke();

        printChange((ReadOnlyProperty<Number>) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
//        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean isResizable() {
//                return true;
//            }
//        };
        canvas.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> repaint(observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));
        canvas.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> repaint(observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));

        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(canvas);
        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5));
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty());
        pane.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                printChange((ReadOnlyDoubleProperty) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));
        pane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                printChange((ReadOnlyDoubleProperty) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(
                Bindings.concat(
                        "Test paint Pixel. Canvas: ", pane.widthProperty().asString(), " x ", pane.heightProperty().asString()
                )
        );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

Below the application when it is launched.

[image: Application when launched]

This is what happens when I resize the application:

[image: Application after resized]

As you can see, the canvas is not redrawn. Instead, the lines are superimposed. Even after calling `GraphicsContext.clearRect()` as suggested in many posts here in StackOverflow.
Besides, if you see the fist image, the pane padding is not working. Actually apparently just the top and left padding are working but not the bottom and right ones. There is not space between canvas' bottom and right and the application windows.

So does Someone have any idea about what is wrong here?

Thanks,

Comment: `Canvas` in non-resizeable (meaning it cannot be automatically resized by its parent). You seem to have noticed this and "fixed" this issue by using `canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty());` However combined with the padding this leaves the `FlowPane` in a state where it cannot do the layout according to the constraints specified, i.e. the result of its `maxWidth` method is bigger than the space allowed by the scene. The resulting layout is not well defined in this case. As for the drawing method: Clear the path before appending more and more lines.

Comment: https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/canvas/GraphicsContext.html#beginPath() Also consider overriding `layoutChildren` for a parent wrapping the `Canvas` to avoid unneccesary redraws and restrict the redrawing to 1 per layout pass.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @fabian suggestions I was able to fix both issues of cleaning canvas and its size. Althought the size adjust is a workaround using pane´s insets.:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.ReadOnlyProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.time.LocalTime;

public class TestPaintColor0 extends Application {

    private void printChange(ReadOnlyProperty<Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue, Canvas canvas) {
        System.out.printf("[%s] %10s.%-10s: %4.0f -> %4.0f. Canvas: %4.0f x %4.0f.\n",
                LocalTime.now(), observable.getBean().getClass().getSimpleName(), observable.getName(), oldValue, newValue,
                canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
    }

    private void repaint(ObservableValue<? extends Number> observable, Number oldValue, Number newValue, Canvas canvas) {
        GraphicsContext gc = canvas.getGraphicsContext2D();

        // Should clear canvas.
        gc.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        // SOLUTION TO CLEAN CANVAS
        gc.beginPath();

        // Paint background
        gc.setFill(Color.PURPLE);
        gc.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());

        // draw diagonals
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.moveTo(0, 0);
        gc.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        gc.moveTo(0, canvas.getHeight());
        gc.lineTo(canvas.getWidth(), 0);
        gc.stroke();

        printChange((ReadOnlyProperty<Number>) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        final Canvas canvas = new Canvas();
        canvas.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> repaint(observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));
        canvas.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> repaint(observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));

        FlowPane pane = new FlowPane(canvas);

        pane.setPadding(new Insets(5));

        // WORKAROUND TO RESIZE CANVAS!!!! - BEGIN!
        canvas.widthProperty().bind(pane.widthProperty().subtract(pane.getInsets().getLeft() + pane.getInsets().getRight()));
        canvas.heightProperty().bind(pane.heightProperty().subtract(pane.getInsets().getTop() + pane.getInsets().getBottom()));
        // WORKAROUND TO RESIZE CANVAS!!!! - END!

        pane.heightProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                printChange((ReadOnlyDoubleProperty) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));
        pane.widthProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) ->
                printChange((ReadOnlyDoubleProperty) observable, oldValue, newValue, canvas));

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(pane, 600, 400));
        primaryStage.titleProperty().bind(
                Bindings.concat(
                        "Test paint Pixel. Canvas: ", pane.widthProperty().asString(), " x ", pane.heightProperty().asString()
                )
        );
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```